# How do I create a for loop that only executes on files larger than a specified filesize?

Tags: bash, macos, find, zsh

I want to split mp4 files that are greater than 500MB into segments smaller than 500MB.

How do I create a for loop to iterate over a directory of files, running

```
mp4box -splits 500000 input.mp4
```

on each file greater than 500 MB?

(The loop part is not a problem. The testing for filesize part is.)

Comment: Why is this tagged bash *and* zsh?

Comment: Because I use both.

Comment: Wouldn't it then make more sense to ask two questions? Imagine that someone gives you an answer valid for bash, and the other one gives an answer valid for zsh, which one would you accept as correct? Also you are creating a script here. It does not matter, which language you use for your daily work. You certainly want to write two versions of your script (bash and zsh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `find` for this:

```
find ./ -name "*.mp4" -size +500M -exec mp4box -splits 500000 {} \;
```

(I didn't test it, but it should be something like that)

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly, and I learned a new argument for find.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
for f ( *.mp4(.Lk+500000) ) mp4box -splits 500000 $f
```

Glob qualifiers: `(.)` to match plain files, `(Lk+500000)` to match files greater than 500000 KB in size. Add `(D)` to the qualifiers to include dotfiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use `find`, e.g.:

```
for file in $( find . -size +500M )
do
    echo $file
done
```

But I don't know if `find` is available with macos.

Comment: Are you aware of the `-exec` switch of the `find` command, as I explained in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I am. OP asked for a loop. In general I prefer xargs over -exec in find, but your answer looks good.

Comment: Your answer indeed resembles more the original question (hence the +1), but in case it's possible to avoid using a loop, I don't hesitate :-)

Comment: You are looping find results wrong because it will word-split file names

Comment: This won't work if `find` returns a filename containing whitespace or glob characters. This is not a correct way to iterate through files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stat to obtain the file size in the loop:

```
stat -c '%s' filename.txt
```

note: The size is in bytes.